# How prove this set isn't dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I want to prove this set $M=\{U \in X ,\  \|U\|\le 1\}$  isn't dense in $X =C[a,b]$.

Can you help me?

Comment: This is like asking if the unit circle is dense in the plane. Is it? Why not?

Comment: I'm sorry i can't understand what do you mean?

Comment: Consider the open ball of radius $1$ centered at $f=2$. Does it contain an element of $M$?

Answer (score 4):

$M$ is the set of elements whose norm is less than $1$. Similarly, the unit disc in the plane is the set of elements whose norm is less than $1$. Now, the unit disc is clearly not dense in the plane. Prove that, and then see if you can apply the same reasoning to the original problem.

Comment: Excuse me now why this set (M)isn't compact in X ?

Comment: I must show this by sequence & use piecewise linear continuous function such that U_n(x)--->0 as n--->   where this convergence isn't uniform on[a,b]

Comment: @mahsa I'm pretty sure $M$ *is* compact. Are you sure that's what you're supposed to prove?

Comment: yes this example is from Zeidler book page 92

Comment: @mahsa You might want to start a new question with some more details.

Comment: M is not compact. Find infinitely many elements such that any pair is at least distance 1 apart.

Comment: @JackM $M$ is compact if and only if it is sequentially compact. Consider the sequence $\{x^n\}$ in $C([0,1])$. Each $x^n\in M$ and hence, each $x^n$ is bounded. But there is no subsequence of $\{x^n\}$ that converges to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

The set is not dense in $C([a,b])$. This means that the closure of $M$ does not equal $C([a,b])$. To see this, let $f\in C([a,b])$ such that $\|f\|=2$. Take the open ball of radius $1/2$ centered at $f$, $B(f,1/2)$. So if $g\in B(f,1/2)$ we have that $3/2< \|g\|< 5/2$. Hence, $g\notin M$ and so $B(f,1/2)\cap M=\emptyset$. Since there exists an open neighborhood of $f$ whose intersection with $M$ is empty, we have that $f$ is not in the closure of $M$. Thus, the closure of $M$ is not equal to $C([a,b])$ and so $M$ is not dense in $C([a,b])$.

Comment: why the ||g|| is between 3/2 & 5/2 ?

Comment: $3/2=2-1/2$ and $5/2=2+1/2$. Since $g$ is within $1/2$ of $f$ and $f$ has norm $2$, $||g||\in(3/2,5/2)$.

Comment: @mahsa this is very easily seen if you draw a picture.