# Why this set $M$ isn't compact in $X$?

Tags: analysis, functions

I want to prove this set $M=\{U\in X, \|U\|≤1\}$ is compact in $X=C[a,b]$

I must show with sequence & use piecewise linear continuous function such that $U_n(x)\to0$ as $n\to$ where this convergence isn't uniform on $[a,b]$.

if any body know pl help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How prove this set isn't dense?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698965/how-prove-this-set-isnt-dense)

Answer (score 0):

$M$ is not compact.

The sequence $f_n(x)=x^n$ is bounded in $X$ but does not have any uniformly convergent subsequence. If you want to do it with piecewise linear functions you can take
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
n\,x & 0\le x\le 1/n,\\
n(2/n-x) & 1/n<x\le2/n,\\
0 & 2/n<x\le1.\end{cases}$$

Comment: I can't understand why $f_n(x)$ =$x^n$ is bounded in X and how related the M is a compact set

Comment: about the second $f_n(x)$ how we reach M is a compact set .furthermore we know a set is compact if each sequence in M have sub sequence $u_n'$---> u as n-->   such that u in M

Comment: $\{x^n\}\subset M$ because $\|x^n\|=1$. Since no subsequence converges uniformly, $M$ is not compact. The same happens with $\{f_n\}$.

Comment: @ Julián Aguirre thank alot